# Lost apple private keys after disk failure

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have developed an IOs app on my MacbookPro laptop, which unfortunately had suffered a disk failure last week, with all data on it being lost.
Dumb as I am, I did not backup any of the keys I had on my laptop. My question is, can I still somehow update my existing application (I do still have my source code) in the app store? Or is it the same case with Google's keystore, where if you lose your key you must create a new application?

Thanks

Comment: Certificates expire once a year. Simply pretend your certificates expired and go through the steps to renew the certificates and update all of your provisioning profiles. This is a non-issue.

Comment: Why cant google do the same :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can update your app easily.  Simply follow the same steps you originally followed to create a new app store distribution profile.  As long as you do not change the app id of the application, it will be the same app.